# Question about the superposition-theorem

Tags: basic

I had this exam question, where I was asked to solve a circuit with the superposition theorem. I did it by mesh analysis because I didn't read correctly, but to check my procedure I did a different version of the superposition theorem.

The superposition theorem states that you should consider the influence that each element taken separately has on the circuit, and then sum those influences.

What I did was that I didn't consider them completely separately. The thing worked and got the right results.

**Important to note** here is that no separate case had repeated elements, OK? For example if I had three elements A,B and C; I would consider the influence of A,B then of C. I did not repeat elements in the distinct scenarios. For example I wouldn't have done A,B and A,C and then sum them.

How can I show that my procedure is in line with the superposition theorem?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't.  Two different theorems which arrive at the same answer.  You say you "did a different version of the superposition theorem" to check. You'll get some marks for that or the fact you got the correct answers, but I'd guess somewhere else they asked you for mesh analysis.  You demonstrated you could do mesh, so it's doubtful they will reward you for not reading the question.

Answer (score 2):

Superposition says that the solution to a linear circuit with multiple sources \$A\$, \$B\$, and \$C\$ is
$$
S_{ABC} = S_A + S_B + S_C
$$
where each \$S_X\$ is the solution with only source \$X\$ active.

You could also write this as
$$
S_{ABC} = (S_A + S_B) + S_C = S_{AB} + S_C
$$
where you've combined sources \$A\$ and \$B\$ before considering \$C\$. That's fine.

What you did was you skipped straight to the last expression: you found \$S_{AB}\$ (without superposition) and used that to help you get the solution. Looks good to me.

Comment: How can I prove that this addition is associative? I'm looking for something to tell my professor Hehe.

Comment: Hmm. If you changed the labels on the sources (say A, B, C -> C, A, B) then you could still use superposition and everything would work out. Does that prove associativity?

Comment: I think you're talking about commutativity, unless I'm misunderstanding you. What I mean is how can I prove that parentheses can in fact be dropped around anywhere in the sum if each $$S_X$$ implies that all the others were off.

Comment: ha, you're right. oops. I guess that superposition is just adding up different solutions on every element of the circuit. That means you're really just asking if adding functions is associative (which it is)

Comment: Addition is associative, from like 8th-grade math. If your prof won't take that as a given, he's got a problem.

Comment: LOL. But I don't think putting parenthesis on ,e.g., $$(S1+S2)$$ clearly implies you've left those 2 elements on while you've left all the rest off. I think it implies that you've found the values of S1 and S2 and then added them.